# Terraform, way to add a condition to use different variable if a variable is empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the following:

```
subnet_mapping = [for i, eip in aws_eip.eip : { allocation_id : eip.id, subnet_id : tolist(data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.public_subnet_ids)[i] }]
```

but in case if someone passes a list of EIP's manually(ex: ext_eips = ["x.x.x.x", "x,x,x,x"]), then I should be able to use the following:

```
subnet_mapping = [for i, eip in var.ext_eips : { private_ipv4_address : tolist(var.ext_eips)[i], subnet_id : tolist(data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.public_subnet_ids)[i] }]
```

With above requirement, could someone please help me in solving this.

Thanks

Comment: Set the default to null and just do a null check

Comment: That looks like multiple syntax issues, but besides that, you could most easily accomplish this with a `locals` block to conditionally assign the value for the `eips`.

Comment: Thanks, was able to solve it with null check.